# pandas string to numeric

Tags: python, pandas, numeric

I have a set of data like

```
        a      b
0  type 1   True
1  type 2  False
```

How can I keep the numerical part of column `a` and transfer ture to 1, false to zero at the same time. Below is what I want.

```
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert Booleans to integers as follows:

```
df['b'] = df.b.astype(int)
```

Depending on the nature of your text in Column `A`, you can do a few things:

a) Split on the space and take the second part (either string or int depending on your needs).

```
df['a'] = df.a.str.split().str[1]  # Optional `.astype(int)`
```

b)  Use regex to extract any digits (`\d*`) from the end of the string.

```
df['a'] = df.a.str.extract(r'(\d*)$')  # Optional `.astype(int)`
```